# Links to the acronym directory only for "real" acronyms in glossaries

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I want links to the acronym directory only for "PC" and not for the rest. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PC}{PC}{Personal Computer}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \gls{PC}
    \item \gls{PC}
    \item \acrshort{PC}
    \item \acrlong{PC}
\end{enumerate}

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the package option `hyperfirst=false` this will suppress hyperlinks on first use but not on subsequent use, so the first instance of `\gls{PC}` won't have a link to the list of acronyms. If you want to explicitly use `\acrlong` without a link, then use `\acrlong*` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym,hyperfirst=false]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PC}{PC}{Personal Computer}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \gls{PC}
    \item \gls{PC}
    \item \acrshort{PC}
    \item \acrlong*{PC}
\end{enumerate}

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

where the coloured text indicates a hyperlink.